# Books to learn to develop Rails Plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, books

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to learn to write "advanced" plugins for the current versione of the framework. In order to do that I would like to buy some books but what I have seen on the Amazon website are two or three year old...

Do you know and\or advice some books for this matter?

P.S.: Also link to good on-line guides are welcome in answers.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Rails 3.0.7 I highly recommend against any books that are "two or three years old."

[Edge RailsGuides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/) contain the latest official guides for Ruby on Rails.  You should check out the `Extending Rails` section.

Edit:
You should also be aware that Rails 3.x plugins are mostly gems now as the original plugin system basically inserted the plugin directly into your codebase.  Gems are much more extensible and don't muck up your codebase.

You should take a look at some popular Rails 3.x extensions out there:

1. https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure
2. https://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication
3. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Some Rails plugins are also just middleware for Rack.

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommand you have a look [at this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/23/a-guide-to-starting-your-own-rails-engine-gem).

It's a tutorial based on the `Enginex` gem which will soon become the base for engines and gem creation.

Answer (score -1):

I'm reading this book right now:

Crafting Rails Applications: Expert Practices for Everyday Rails Development by José Valim

http://pragprog.com/book/jvrails/crafting-rails-applications